# clone a specific branch from git through ansible playbook

Tags: github, ansible

I am using ansible to deploy my app. I am cloning the app from github using the following:

```
- name: Deploy site files from Github repository
  sudo: yes
  git: repo=git@github.com:xyz/abc.git dest=/home/{{deploy_user}}/{{app_name}} key_file=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa accept_hostkey=yes force=yes
```

I want to clone a specific branch from the repository. I read the documentation of ansible but couldn't find any option to clone a specific branch. It has an option to clone a version but not branch.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html):

> version
>
> What version of the repository to check out. This can be the full 40-character SHA-1 hash, the literal string HEAD, **a branch name**, or a tag name.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Note: the docu is now at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#parameter-version

Answer (score 42):

Use `version`, here's the example from the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html):

```
- git:
    repo: git://foosball.example.org/path/to/repo.git
    dest: /srv/checkout
    version: dev
```

Comment: Note: the docu is now at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#parameter-version