# Git clone branch (that isn't HEAD) via Ansible playbook?

Tags: git, ansible

If you have an Ansible playbook and you want to create a task that checks out a specific branch, this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450240/clone-a-specific-branch-from-git-through-ansible-playbook/41187375) says to do this:

```
- git:
    repo: git://foosball.example.org/path/to/repo.git
    dest: /srv/checkout
    version: dev
```

Although `version` can be the literal string "HEAD", a branch name, a tag, or a 40-character SHA-1 hash, this example assumes that you want to check out the HEAD branch.  But what do you do if you have two branches, say a "dev" branch which is a child of a "master" branch, and you want to check out an older commit from the dev branch using a SHA-1 hash?  How would you do that?  If dev has not yet been merged into master, you would need to specify both the branch name "dev" *and* the hash.  But Ansible doesn't seem to have a separate parameter to allow you do to this.  There is a `refspec` parameter but I'm not sure you can specify a hash in it.  In this situation, would you just have to do a `fetch` and `checkout` using the Ansible `command` task and specify the hash in the checkout task?

Comment: Why not just `version: SHA-1`?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm wondering.  How does Ansible know which branch to fetch for a given SHA-1, master or dev? And if you have master <- dev <- new_feature and a given hash is in both dev and new_feature, shouldn't you specify a branch? Sorry if these sound like dumb questions but I'm new to Git.

Comment: "*How does Ansible know which branch to fetch…?*" It doesn't. It just passes the job to `git`; `git` also doesn't know — it fetches enough commits up to the given SHA-1. Branches are not interesting as branches are just labels for commits; commits and chains are interesting but having a SHA-1 reference `git` will fetch all necessary objects.

Comment: "*If…a given hash is in both dev and new_feature, shouldn't you specify a branch?*" Not necessary. `git checkout SHA-1` leads to ["detached head"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304087/7976758), with or without ansible.